# ordering X axis based on Y axis on python

Tags: python, ggplot2

Im using the code bellow to plot number of clicks by user.
My dataframe is ordered descending:

```
          name   value
0  xxxx xxxxxxx  215930
1     yyyyyyyyy  176058
2        zzzzzz  143640
3        qqqqqq  101732
```

but the bars are randomly plotted.

```
print ggplot(aes(x="name", y="value"), df)  + geom_bar(stat='bar', fill='blue') + theme(axis_text_x  = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) + ylab("Count") + xlab("User")
```

[image]

How can I make the bars (x axis) be ordered by the value on Y?

Thanks

Comment: By default, the order is lexical. If it was `r`, the answer would be to [reorder factor levels](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208679/order-bars-in-ggplot2-bar-graph), but I'm unsure if that's possible from python.

Comment: Actually, adding `+ scale_x_discrete(limits = c("x", "y", "q", "z"))` would also work, see if you can adapt that without messing with the data.

Comment: thanks, but that presumes you know in advance the order, doesnt it?

Comment: 1) If `df` is already sorted, then (using R notation) `+ scale_x_discrete(limits = df$name))`, otherwise 2) check the accepted answer I linked, it has `sort` in there.